# When do we use the indifinte article "a" with abstract nouns?

Tags: indefinite-article, abstract-nouns

Why we used the indifinte article "a" in this sentence ??
"Fear is a universal weakness"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The level of abstraction is only one consideration. Another is countability.

In this case, you have identified **fear** as one *kind* of **weaknesses**. Depending on the context, other qualities could also be considered weaknesses: **pity, mental instability, lack of empathy**, etc.

Contrast this with a noun like **happiness**. There are many things that can *cause* you to experience **happiness**, just as there are many *degrees* of happiness. (I am somewhat happy, I am very happy, this is the happiest I have ever been.) But for most people, there is only one *kind* of **happiness.**

Another contributor indicates that when an abstract noun is modified by an adjective (such as **universal**) the noun becomes countable because the adjective distinguishes that noun from other instances of the noun. But this point is incomplete. The following would also be correct:

> Fear is a weakness.
> Pity is a weakness.
> Lack of empathy is a weakness.

In each case, it is the statement itself that makes **weakness** countable. **Fear** is distinct from **pity** and all the other kinds of **weakness**.

This does not mean that **weakness** is always countable. All of these sentences are permissible:

> 1. I feel weakness in my arm.
> 2. I feel a weakness in my arm.
> 3. I feel a slight weakness in my arm.

2 and 3 assumes that we can experience **weakness** in more than one way. 1 assumes that there is one kind of **weakness** and we experience it in a similar way in all of our body parts. The speaker's decision to use an article or not reveals his *attitude* toward **weakness**.

Comment: You are right, but "weakness" that you show us is limited to one of several definitions of a word " weakness". According to dictionary. The "weakness" is countable and the meaning of the word is a weak point in a system, somebody’s character, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> "Fear is a universal weakness"

An adjective "universal" modifies an abstract noun "weakness".
That is, when an uncountable noun is modified by an adjective.
An article "a" is used in front of an adjective.